# Apache NMS IBytesMessage has a prefix after dequeuing

Tags: c#, .net, activemq-classic, amqp

I've tried my best to figure this out, but I'm guessing my inexperience with Dotnet/C# and message queues is showing through.

### The problem

In a nutshell the situation I'm dealing with is, I have two projects.

The **first** project is a legacy Dotnet project using the Apache NMS library to consume messages from an ActiveMQ queue.

The queue is normally connected in production via SSL, but developing locally I have connected via TCP which all works fine and actively connects & dequeues as expected.

Once the messages are dequeued they are deserialised using the JsonConvert DeserializeObject method.

The **second** project is a NodeJS project which I've created to put messages onto the queue.

The messages are just a simple object, stringified to JSON.

I'm using the AMQP Rhea [npm package](https://github.com/amqp/rhea) to connect and send the messages, in AMQP format.

This again all works fine and the messages are enqueued as expected.

The problem is when I come to deserialising the message pulled from the queue.

There's an exception because it encounters a prefix to my JSON message - I have no idea where the prefix comes from.

I have a creeping suspicion it's because there's a clash between the protocols I'm using and that's causing the issue, but before I find myself in that particular rabbit hole - or just resorting to using a shaky method of removing the prefix - I'm hoping one of you with more experience can help point me in the right direction.

---

### Code

Here's a couple of snippets of the offending C#:

This is how I'm dequeueing the messages:

```
    string dequeuedMessage = string.Empty;
    List<string> messages = new List<string>();

    IMessage message = _consumer.Receive(waitForMessage);

    if (message is ITextMessage || message is IBytesMessage)
    {

        dequeuedMessage = (message is ITextMessage) ? (message as ITextMessage).Text : Encoding.UTF8.GetString((message as IBytesMessage).Content);
        messages.Add(dequeuedMessage);
    }
    else
        break;
```

What's interesting is the message *always* comes through as type IBytesMessage, not what the previous author was expecting (ITextMessage), which is why I'm having that creeping suspicion.

And this is how I'm deserialising the message:

```
    private IMessage BuildMessageObject(string message)
    {
        IMessage convertedMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueueMessage>(message);
            
        return convertedMessage;
    }
```

---

Here's a look at the prefix:

```
\0SpE\0SsE\0Sw\xb1\0\0\x01\xac{"Message":"Message Content Snipped for Brevity"}
```

It appears to always be the same, so maybe it means something to someone.

### What I've Tried & Expectations

To quickly debug, I tried connecting to the queue in the Dotnet project using AMQP, but it appears that the Apache NMS package doesn't support this.

I'm not in a position to completely rewrite the connection with another package either.

I've also written something to dequeue the message in my Node app and I get the JSON back without the prefix, but this connects with the AMQP protocol which may be why?

Thanks for **any** help.

Edit: I should add that I'm using ActiveMQ Classic and not Artemis.

Comment: Messages produced or consumed using different protocols _should_ have the same bodies since one of the main goals of the broker is protocol interoperability. Therefore, this could be a bug in either the producer, consumer, or the broker itself. You could try using ActiveMQ Artemis instead of ActiveMQ "Classic" and if the problem goes away then you know it's likely a problem with the broker. If not, then it's more likely it's a bug in either the consumer or producer.

Comment: Generally speaking, I'd recommend using AMQP vs. OpenWire as AMQP is an OASIS standard with active support across a number of languages and platforms. OpenWire is specific to ActiveMQ. Also, it's worth noting that there's an [AMQP "provider" available for NMS](https://activemq.apache.org/components/nms/providers/amqp/).

Comment: @JustinBertram thank you for your help, even though I've "solved" the issue for now, at some point we're likely to be updating the legacy project even further so I'll keep everything you said in mind to properly refactor everything.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, it appears it is an issue with the amqp/rhea package and using the AMQP protocol as I suspected.

The problem, without running into details I can't fully explain, is that the message from the queue has been encoded and the message body includes that encoding.

The NMS library uses ActiveMQ's native OpenWire protocol.

I'm probably going to have to resolve this by moving from using the amqp/rhea package and trying to find an openwire equivalent - which is preferable than trying to find an AMQP equivalent for the Dotnet project.

**Edit:**

As it turns out, the rhea package is sufficient to solve the problem.
In sending the message body, I've instead created it as a Buffer instead of type Message:

```
const messageAsBuffer = Buffer.from(message);
sender.send(messageAsBuffer, undefined, 1);
```

where *undefined* can be a message tag and *1* can be any integer that is not 0, specifying the message is not in AMQP format.

Comment: Did you ensure that the broker is using the JMS transformer for AMQP transportConnector ("transport.transformer=jms").  If using a native or raw transformer the message you receiver would likely be the encoded AMQP message

Comment: Hi @TimBish, I haven't - the broker just runs in a Docker container and hasn't been modified from its base image at all, so that could possibly be another way to resolve something like this. It also ties in with what Justin was suggesting about it being a problem with the broker, so you're very likely onto something.

Comment: See the ActiveMQ documentation section about Mapping https://activemq.apache.org/amqp you would need to ensure the mapping is set to JMS for Openwire to AMQP interop